# CSharp: How to goto next tab by pressing a button

Tags: c#

What would be the algorithm to make it so upon pressing a button inside the first tab of a tab control so that you get switched to second tab.

Answer (score 4):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2/*needed tab*/;
```